# how to plus and minus when button is clicked in uitabelview row and section and reload like foodpanda

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am creating app link food panda.let me explain the flow.I have a vc with table with rows and sections when i click on section it will expand and collapsing rows.in the section there is add button in each rows.wqhen i click on add button in section 3 row the button should hide and + and - button should show like the image given below.

[image]

2.when i click on the pluse and minus button it should add to cart and money should increase and decrease amount in cart i used below code for expand and collapse sections.

```
 @implementation menulistingVC

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[super viewDidLoad];
menuarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 arrselectedrow=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
apiCall = [[APICall alloc]init];
 isMultipleExpansionAllowed = NO;

 arrSelectedSectionIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (!isMultipleExpansionAllowed) {
    [arrSelectedSectionIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countt+20]];
}


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(loadtable:)
                                             name:@"array" object:nil];
_tblview.estimatedRowHeight = 69;
_tblview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
  -(void)loadtable:(NSNotification*)notification
 {
isMultipleExpansionAllowed = NO;
arrSelectedSectionIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (!isMultipleExpansionAllowed) {
    [arrSelectedSectionIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countt+20]];
}


[self getingfooddeatilsbacedonclub:[notification object]];


 }
  -(void)getingfooddeatilsbacedonclub:(NSString *)typestr{
  _clubstr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
 stringForKey:@"newclubid"];

//    accessToken=[defaults valueForKey:@"accessToken"];
//    clubberId = [defaults valueForKey:@"idClubber_dtls"];

if (![APICall hasNetwork])
{
    [Util displayToastMessage:@"No internet connection"];
}else
{


    [customBezelActivityView activityViewForView:self.view];
    NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s/presignin/menu/list/category/by_venue?clubId=%@&type=%@",urlPath,_clubstr,typestr];
    NSLog(@"getherd :%@",urlstr);
    [apiCall getArrayFromApiwithstauscode:urlstr restfulType:kRestfulGet andUseContentType:NO withRequestBody:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *result, NSInteger statuscodeint){

        NSLog(@"classifieds List response:%@",result);
        NSLog(@"statuscode List response:%ld",(long)statuscodeint);
        if (statuscodeint==200) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [customBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
               menuarray=[result mutableCopy];

                 isMultipleExpansionAllowed = NO;

                if (!isMultipleExpansionAllowed) {
                    [arrSelectedSectionIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countt+20]];
                }
                [_tblview reloadData];

            });

        }else if (statuscodeint==401){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [customBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
                UIStoryboard *storyBoard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                SignInViewController *SignINViewController=[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignINViewController"];
                [self presentViewController:SignINViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            });

        }

    }];

   }


  }

   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
    return menuarray.count;
   }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {

     if ([arrSelectedSectionIndex containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]])
{
     NSArray *arr=[menuarray[section] valueForKey:@"menu"];
    return arr.count;
}else{
    return 0;
}
}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenudetailsTblCell";

menudetailscell = ( MenudetailsTblCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (menudetailscell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenudetailsTblCell" owner:self options:nil];
    menudetailscell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

}



if (menudetailscell == nil)
{
    menudetailscell = [[MenudetailsTblCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
menudetailscell.detailview.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
menudetailscell.detailview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
if (indexPath.row==0) {
    menudetailscell.toplbl.hidden=YES;
}else{
    menudetailscell.toplbl.hidden=NO;
}
menudetailscell.addbtntocart.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
menudetailscell.addbtntocart.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
menudetailscell.addbtntocart.tag=indexPath.row;
menudetailscell.plusebtn.tag=indexPath.row;
menudetailscell.minusbtn.tag=indexPath.row;
menudetailscell.plusebtn.hidden=YES;
menudetailscell.minusbtn.hidden=YES;
menudetailscell.noofitemslbl.hidden=YES;
NSArray *arr=[menuarray[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"menu"];
menudetailscell.typelbl.text=[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
 menudetailscell.describtionlbl.text=[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"description"];
NSString *cost=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"price"],@".00"];
    NSString *imgid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"idmenus"]];
NSString *tax=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"tax"]];
if ([tax isEqualToString:@"tax"]) {
  menudetailscell.taxlbl.text=@"(*Inclusive of all taxes)";
}else{

menudetailscell.taxlbl.text=@"(*Exclusive of all taxes)";
}
menudetailscell.ratelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"country"],cost];
  [ menudetailscell.addbtntocart addTarget:self action:@selector(addbtnclicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NSString *typeimgUrl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s/presignin/menu/showMedia?idMenu=%@",urlPath,imgid];
NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:typeimgUrl1];
menudetailscell.imgview.imageURL=imageURL;
[menudetailscell.plusebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pluseTapShowHideSection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[menudetailscell.minusbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(minusTapShowHideSection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
menudetailscell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return menudetailscell;


 }



-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{



static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Menusectioncell";

menusectioncell = ( Menusectioncell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (menusectioncell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Menusectioncell" owner:self options:nil];
    menusectioncell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

}



if (menusectioncell == nil)
{
    menusectioncell = [[Menusectioncell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


if ([arrSelectedSectionIndex containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]])
{
   // right-arrow   //down-arrow
    menusectioncell.Sectiomtitlebtn.selected = YES;
     menusectioncell.dotlbl.hidden=NO;
    menusectioncell.expandtypeimg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow"];
}
else{
menusectioncell.dotlbl.hidden=YES;
    menusectioncell.expandtypeimg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-arrow"];
}

menusectioncell.Sectiomtitlebtn.tag=section;


menusectioncell.dotlbl.layer.cornerRadius = menusectioncell.dotlbl.frame.size.height/2;
menusectioncell.dotlbl.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

[menusectioncell.Sectiomtitlebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapShowHideSection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NSString *btntitle=[menuarray[section] valueForKey:@"catagory"];
itemarr=[menuarray[section] valueForKey:@"menu"];
NSString *items=[itemarr[0] valueForKey:@"name"];
menusectioncell.sectiontitleilb.text=btntitle;
if (itemarr.count==1) {
  menusectioncell.itemslbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",items];
}else{
NSString *seconditemstr=[itemarr[1] valueForKey:@"name"];
menusectioncell.itemslbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@ etc..",items,seconditemstr];
}

menusectioncell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return menusectioncell.contentView;

}

  -(IBAction)btnTapShowHideSection:(UIButton*)sender
 {
int section=sender.tag;


if (!sender.selected)
{

    //originallcode
    if (!isMultipleExpansionAllowed) {
        [arrSelectedSectionIndex addObject:@"-1"];
        [arrSelectedSectionIndex replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]];
    }else {

        NSLog(@"%@",arrSelectedSectionIndex);
        [arrSelectedSectionIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]];
    }
    menusectioncell.dotlbl.hidden=YES;
    menusectioncell.expandtypeimg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-arrow"];
    sender.selected = YES;
}
else{
    sender.selected = NO;
    menusectioncell.dotlbl.hidden=NO;
    menusectioncell.expandtypeimg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow"];
    if ([arrSelectedSectionIndex containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]])
    {
        [arrSelectedSectionIndex removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]];
    }
}

if (!isMultipleExpansionAllowed) {
    [_tblview reloadData];
}else {
    [_tblview reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sender.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}

 }

 - (void)addbtnclicked:(UIButton *)sender
 {
menudetailscell.plusebtn.hidden=NO;
menudetailscell.minusbtn.hidden=NO;
menudetailscell.noofitemslbl.hidden=NO;
menudetailscell.addbtntocart.hidden=YES;
int rowselect=sender.tag;
[arrselectedrow addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]];
NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:sectionselect];

[self.tblview beginUpdates];
[self.tblview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath1, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tblview endUpdates];


 }
 - (void)pluseTapShowHideSection:(UIButton *)sender
{



  }
   - (void)minusTapShowHideSection:(UIButton *)sender
  {

if ([arrselectedrow containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]])
{
    [arrselectedrow removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]];
}

[self.tblview beginUpdates];
[self.tblview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:arrselectedrow, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tblview endUpdates];

}
```

Comment: You should ask a specific question rather than providing a list of requirements and a code dump.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for quick responce,my requirement is when you click on add btn in cell in an row then add btun in that particular  should hidden and I have pluse btn,minus i have show them in that row and when i click on + and - btn the quality label count should increase in that particular row.